# Function returned string.c_str() as a parameter of atoi() unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, function, parameters, atoi

I have encountered a problem and have no idea why it is occurring. Basically I have a nasty function which parses a text file and returns next entries of multiple values stored in a line after desired parameter name. It works and I don't think it is necessary to post its code. But the problem is: inside a loop I want to use a one liner to assign an integer value returned from *atoi()* to a variable:

```
for (...)
{
    int fieldId = atoi(fileParser.getNextValueOfParameter("fieldIdArray").c_str());
    std::cout << fieldId << " ";
}
```

Unfortunately the first value assigned to a *fieldId* variable during the first loop pass is always *0*. The rest of values are assigned correctly.

However, when instead of one-liner assignment I use a *string* to store text returned by my parsing function and then separately assign its converted numeric value to an *int* - everything works perfectly:

```
for (...)
{
    std::string fieldIdString = fileParser.getNextValueOfParameter("fieldIdArray");
    int fieldId = atoi(fieldIdString.c_str());
    std::cout << fieldId << " ";
}
```

All values are corresponding to actual text numbers stored inside my file. There is no *0* value assigned during the first loop pass.

These two codes are different only in a matter of using temporary *string* variable to store text, before converting it as *.c_str()* inside *atoi()*, as its parameter.

Why is it happening?
I am using a TDM-GCC 4.7.1 32 bit compiler if this is important.

Comment: Why are you using `atoi` in a C++ program?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, because with this bugged compiler version I can not use _std::stoi_ and I wanted a quick workaround which is _atoi()_ and I expected it to work.

Comment: What is the return type of `getNextValueOfParameter`? Breaking into two lines does two things: (1) It extends the lifetime of the return value, and (2) it makes a copy of the return value if the return value is a reference.

Comment: @RaymondChen, it is a _std::string_ and in this case in this particular loop it is always a set of number characters: _1_, _12_, _88_ etc., no letters or other symbols. Then I want to pass it to _atoi()_ as a parameter but also including _.c_str()_ after my function evaluation because _atoi()_ requires C-style string. So it should firstly get a _string_, then convert it to C-style string and finally the result is passed as a _atoi()_ parameter but as I said it is not working the same way as using a temporary variable, just to store a _string_ returned by function and then converting separately

Comment: @wowowo: How is `fileParser.getNextValueOfParameter()` defined? There's no way to say definitively from what you posted, but I suspect that undefined behavor is at play here. Like your `fileParser.getNextValueOfParameter("fieldIdArray")` returns a reference to a local variable and then `c_str()` is applied to that dead reference.

Comment: @AnT ok, here is the code but please don't laugh, I am aware that it can be done in another way http://pastebin.com/3tUU1rN5 

So, even after putting only 
`std::cout << fileParser.getNextValueOfParameter("fieldIdArray").c_str() << " ";`
 to the loop code everything is printed perfectly, every single value is printed as it should be with its proper value, but when passed as a one-liner inside atoi() it always returns 0 at first pass. It is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

atoi basically convert a string having a number in to integer one and whatever it will convert that will become the return value for it. OR to be more precise atoi function start checking from the beginning of string. if it has digit(from the begining only) then it will return that value in integer. Below example will clear the concept For example

```
atoi("1234") 
--> it will convert string "1234" in to integer and return it 
--> i.e. ouput is 1234
atoi("1234abcd") --> i.e. ouput is 1234
atoi("a1234abcd") --> i.e. ouput is 0
```

So if your string contains character first then integer , it will give weired output. Also read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: The content of a _fieldIdString_ is always exclusively a set of number characters. I provided an example in which everything works as it is supposed to but it uses an additional temporary _string_ variable assignment, which then is passed as _c_str()_ to _atoi()_ and I do not understand why it does not work as a one liner, when both my _string_ returning function and conversion to _c_str()_ are evaluated as a _atoi()_ parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this in `C++`

```
int fieldId = atoi(fieldIdString.c_str());
```

to

```
int fieldId = std::stoi(fieldIdString);
```

or

```
int fieldId = std::stoi(fileParser.getNextValueOfParameter("fieldIdArray"));
```